# Error when trying to install machine package with pip

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi

I want to install the python module "machine" with: `pip install machine`

Then it loads a bit and multiple errors occur:

```
Collecting machine
  Using cached machine-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "intmax_t"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "rem"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "}"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "imaxdiv_t"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Number"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Number"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Numerator"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Numerator"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ","
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, machine
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycrypto did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
              standards-based tools.

              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "intmax_t"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "rem"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "}"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "imaxdiv_t"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Number"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Number"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "_Numerator"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "_Numerator"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ";"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ","
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt "{" vor "__cdecl"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pycrypto

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Can you help me to solve this Problem. This Problem also occurs with other modules ( i tried rpi.gpio too)

Thanks for helping me!

I tried some commands i found on the internet, but it didn't help. I dont know which commands i tried anymore

Comment: You're running Windows on a Raspberry Pi???

Comment: WHY do you want to install `machine`?  It's pointless, and hopelessly outdated.  What's your real goal here?